# QProcess start with files from stdin and stdout

Tags: qt, stdout, stdin, qprocess

I need to run following statement from QProcess:

```
programm < file1 > file2
```

in QT:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
proc->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
proc->start("program < \"file1\" > \"file2\"", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

But somehow it does not work. I see in taskmanager, that the command looks correctly, but it seems as the program is executed without any arguments. Where is my error?

Comment: `ReadWrite` is the default mode, so you don't have to specify it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading from and writing into files using `<` respectively `>` is a syntax feature of the shell. If you run the command line `programm < file1 > file2` using a shell like `sh`, the command `program` gets executed only, with no arguments at all. Assigning the programs channels for input and output to the given files doesn't have anything to do with the command itself.

But `QProcess` can be told to simulate this behaviour by using these methods:

[`QProcess::setStandardInputFile(QString fileName)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qprocess.html#setStandardInputFile)
[`QProcess::setStandardOutputFile(QString fileName)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputFile)

So your code becomes:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
proc->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
proc->setStandardInputFile("file1");
proc->setStandardOutputFile("file2");
proc->start("program");
```

Comment: That's interesting! I already tried that, but it did not work. QProcess ignores the working directory for the files. I had to specify them with the full path. Thank you!

Comment: @Oliver Note that working directory != application directory. And maybe QProcess uses even another directory to lookup the files...